# Show that any nonempty set with a lower bound is well ordered.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A lower bound for a set of real numbers, $S$, is defined as a number, $b$, such that $b\leq s$ for every $s \in S$.

A set of numbers is well ordered when each of its nonempty subsets has a minimum element.

Using the fact (*) that for any non-negative integer $n$, the set of integers $\geq -n$ is well ordered:

Show that any set of integers with a lower bound is well ordered.

Wouldn't a counter-example be a set with lower bound of $-100$ because you can't apply the fact (labeled *)?

New to set theory.

Comment: Nonempty set of what? Integers? Real numbers?

Comment: integers, I have edited the question.

Comment: The fact $(*)$ *can* be applied to a set with lower bound of $-100$, by setting $n=100$.